# QGIS Linear Z interpolation on snapping

Tags: qgis, editing, interpolation, 3d, snapping

The interpolation of the Z value when snapping in the creation of a new feature is done well in QGIS 3.14, but when editing elements this does not happen. Is there any way to do it?

[image]